# SQLite - create standalone sequence (get autoincrement integer without the need of having table)

Tags: python, sqlite, influxdb

I am trying to fix an issue with InfluxDB, where it does not support sequences (unique, incremental Integer column). The workaround I have "invented" is, to create an unique Id outside of Influx, when transforming data into data Points.

So my workflow is like:
1.) get set of data
2.) Extract one for at a time
3.) generate unique Id for this row by external DB engine (postgres, sqlite)
4.) Create data point that will be row data + this unique Id as a separate tag
5.) Write hole dataset standard way

That seems like good workaround, ID will be unique and creation of sequence is not hard task for Postgres. All I need to do is to create sequence, and than call `SELECT next_val` everytime I need unique Id. Postgres engine will make sure each integer I get is unique.

However, I do not have postgresql available in enviroment where my code will be running. I have only SQLite. I was so naive, that I thought "its so easy and native, each SQL DB engine has to have it". Well, no, after whole day of investigation, it seems like there is no way of using SQLite sequences outside of the table for which it was created.

Or is there a way?

Yes, I can use more workaround, like stored procedure, where I will add new row to table with autoincrement ID column, delete previous row and than return ID of last row. But I was wondering if there is no simpler / more natural way of achieving my goal (which is, to have command, which when I call into SQLlite, it will return me unique autoincremented integer.

Comment: Create a table with just an `AUTO INCREMENT` column. When you need the next ID, insert a row into that table and get its ID. To keep the table from taking up lots of space, you can then delete the row you created.

Comment: While this is basically what I want to do, it has to be done inside one transaction, to make sure, that the ID which I did get, is not getting also someone else.

Comment: SQLite ensures that automatically. It will not give the same ID to different callers.